# UTF8 Byte to String & Winsock GetStream

Tags: c#, utf-8, winsock, utf8-decode

Well, I'm trying to convert a large information in bytes for string. (11076 length)

The problem in the end, the information is with missing characters. (length 10996)

Look:

[image]

The information is received by Winsock connection, look the proccess:

> ```
>     public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client)
>     {
>         string data = null;
>         Decoder utf8Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
>
>             Console.WriteLine("Iniciando");
>             byte[] buffer = ReadFully(client.TCPClient.GetStream(), 0);
>             int charCount = utf8Decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
>             Char[] chars = new Char[charCount];
>             int charsDecodedCount = utf8Decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, chars, 0);
>
>             foreach (Char c in chars)
>             {
>                 data = data + String.Format("{0}", c);
>             }
>
>             int buffersize = buffer.Length;
>             Console.WriteLine("Chars is: " + chars.Length);
>             Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
>             Console.WriteLine("Byte is: " + buffer.Length);
>             Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
>             Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
>     }
>
>     public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
>     {
>         if (initialLength < 1)
>         {
>             initialLength = 32768;
>         }
>
>         byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
>         int read = 0;
>
>         int chunk;
>
>         chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read);
>
>         checkreach:
>             read += chunk;
>
>             if (read == buffer.Length)
>             {
>                 int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
>
>                 if (nextByte == -1)
>                 {
>                     return buffer;
>                 }
>
>                 byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
>                 Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
>                 newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
>                 buffer = newBuffer;
>                 read++;
>                 goto checkreach;
>             }
>
>         byte[] ret = new byte[read];
>         Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
>         return ret;
>     }
> ```

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Comment: Ewww `goto`. You should rewrite your buffer copying code.

Comment: Yep, error, but this is not the problem.

Comment: Are you sending the right number of characters? It looks like you need to encode the string into UTF bytes then send the byte array length instead of the string length of the UTF bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly normal for UTF-8 encoded text to be more bytes than the number of characters. In UTF-8 some characters (for example [á](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E1/index.htm) and [ã](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm)) are encoded into two or more bytes.

As the `ReadFully` method returns garbage if you try to use it to read more than fits in the initial buffer or if it can't read the entire stream with one `Read` call, you shouldn't use it. Also the way that the char array is converted to a string is extremely slow. Just use a `StreamReader` to read the stream and decode it to a string:

```
public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client) {
  string data;
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.TCPClient.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
  Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
  Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
}
```

Comment: I received the error > Stream reader" does not contain a definition for "data""

Comment: @user3571412: I made some small corrections to the code right after posting the answer. Update the page so that you see the current code.

Comment: The problem persist, now with a new one "Syntax error ','"

Comment: @user3571412: Sorry, just a missing parenthesis in the `using` statement.

Comment: Now, nothing happens when I receive data.

Comment: @user3571412: Perhaps that kind of stream can't be read to end? The `ReadFully` seems to be supposed to do that, but it actually doesn't, so that might be why it "works" in your case.